# Formula works fine if written directly into cell, but doesn't work if set by Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm setting up a Google Sheet with the following structure: Column 'B' is titled 'Question', 'C' Student's Answers', 'D' 'Correct Answer', and 'E' 'Correction'. The sheet compares the cells from column 'C' and 'D'. Column 'E' displays 'Correct' if C and D were equal and 'Verify' otherwise. The user than verifies the rows which were not equal to decide if it is correct or not by selecting "Correct" or "Incorrect" from the dropdown list. In the end, the user gets the total number of "Correct" answers.

Every time the user verifies a row and select "Correct" or "Incorrect" from the dropdown menu in column 'E', the formula that was comparing 'C' and 'D' gets replaced by the value selected forcing the user to rewrite the formula in those cells if he wants to use the same sheet with different values for columns 'C' and/or 'D'.

So, I'm using an onEdit Apps Script function that refreshes column 'E' contents back to the desired formula. In my case this happens every time cell 'C2' is edited.

**The formula I'm trying to put in the cell looks like this:**

```
'=IF(INDIRECT("RC[-2]";FALSE)=INDIRECT("RC[-1]";FALSE); "Correct"; "Verify")'
```

**See below the full script:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var targetRange = ss.getRangeList(['E47:E51', 'E53:E57', 'E59:E63', 'E65:E67']);
  var formulaR1C1 = '=IF(INDIRECT("RC[-2]";FALSE)=INDIRECT("RC[-1]";FALSE); "Correct"; "Verify")'
  
  if (ss.getName() !== 'Sheet_Name' || range !== 'C2') {
    return;
  }
  targetRange.setFormulaR1C1(formulaR1C1);
}
```

**The problem:** The formula is written correctly within the cells, but it raises '#ERROR!'.
If I write exactly the same formula by hand, not using Apps script, it works perfectly. For some reason though, when this same formula is set by Apps Script the '#ERROR! Formula parse error' comes up.

I'd like to know how I could make this work.

I aprecciate your attention, cheers.

[Top: function inserted manually, Bottom: function inserted via Apps script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NinWn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var formulaR1C1 = '=IF(INDIRECT("RC[-2]";FALSE)=INDIRECT("RC[-1]";FALSE); "Correct"; "Verify")'
```

#### To:

```
var formulaR1C1 = '=IF(RC[-2]=RC[-1]; "Correct"; "Verify")';
```

- When this modification is reflected in your script and test it, the cell "E47" has a formula of `=IF(C47=D47, "Correct", "Verify")`. Is this formula your expected result?

Comment: Wow, thanks! Your sugestion worked. 
Not using 'INDIRECT' when unsing the method setFormulaR1C1 fixed the problem.